# Powershell to trigger ACR BUILD failing when called from windows scheduler

Tags: windows, azure, docker, powershell, azure-container-registry

I have been trying to schedule an ACR BUILD on a machine using Powershell. The approach I am using is with a service principal (as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli)

I have created a build script which works fine, if I call it form within the Powershell console. However, when I schedule the script to run from the windows scheduler, it seems to skip past the ACR BUILD portion and not execute as expected.

Script below:

```
$myreg = "myreg"
$myregfull = "myreg.azurecr.io"
$Date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
$logfile = "c:\Log-$Date.txt"
$user ="xxx"
$pass="xxx"
$tenant="xxx"
$subscription="xxx"
$myimage="myimage:"

Try {
    # 1. Logging in as service principal
    $DateForLog = Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    "--- Logging in as service principal ---" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    az login --service-principal -u $user -p $pass --tenant $tenant  | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}
Catch{
    "Logging in as service principal failed at $(Get-Date). Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | 
        Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}

Try {
    # 2. Switching to subscription
    $DateForLog = Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    "--- Switching to subscription ---" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    az account set --subscription $subscription | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}
Catch{
    "Switching to subscription failed at $(Get-Date). Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | 
        Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}

Try {
    # 3. Logging in to registry
    $DateForLog = Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    "--- Logging in to registry $myreg.azurecr.io ---" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    $TOKEN=$(az acr login --name $myreg --expose-token --output tsv --query accessToken)
    docker login $myregfull -u 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 -p $TOKEN | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}
Catch{
    "Logging in to registry failed at $(Get-Date). Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | 
        Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}

Try {
    # 4. Confirm connected
    $DateForLog = Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    "--- Confirming connected ---" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    az acr show -n $myreg | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    az acr repository list -n $myreg | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}
Catch{
    "Confirm connected failed at $(Get-Date). Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | 
        Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}

Try {
    # 5. Triggerng Build
    $DateForLog = Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    "--- Triggering build of myreg.azurecr.io/myimage:initial ---" | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
    az acr build -t $myimage$Date -r $myreg . --platform windows | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}
Catch{
    "Triggerng Build failed at $(Get-Date). Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" | 
        Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
}

$DateForLog = Get-Date | Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Append
```

When called from console, the logs show the command called, then some 15mins later (after context upload) it shows (etc). :
2022/06/14 10:26:12 Downloading source code...
Then taking approx 30 mins to build before moving to next step.

Whereas when called form scheduler, it shows the step being finished in 8 secs.

The login process is definitely successful though, because the list of repositories is shown, no matter where it is called form.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Updating the question to show logs.

From scheduler:

```
14 June 2022 14:46:05
--- Logging in as service principal ---
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "xxx",
    --- OMMITTED ---
    "user": {
      "name": "xxx",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
14 June 2022 14:46:31
--- Switching to subscription ---
14 June 2022 14:46:36
--- Logging in to registry myreg.azurecr.io ---
Logging in to registry failed at 06/14/2022 14:46:47. Error: The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
14 June 2022 14:46:47
--- Confirming connected ---
{
  "adminUserEnabled": true,
  "anonymousPullEnabled": false,
  "creationDate": "2021-04-06T10:23:22.985285+00:00",
  --- OMMITTED --- 
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
  "zoneRedundancy": "Disabled"
}
[
  "myrepo1",
  --- OMMITTED --- 
  "myrepo2"
]
14 June 2022 14:47:03
--- Triggering build of myreg.azurecr.io/myimage:initial ---
14 June 2022 14:47:12
```

From console:

```
14 June 2022 14:50:14
--- Logging in as service principal ---
[
  {
    "cloudName": "AzureCloud",
    "homeTenantId": "xxx",
    --- OMMITTED ---
    "user": {
      "name": "xxx",
      "type": "servicePrincipal"
    }
  }
]
14 June 2022 14:50:41
--- Switching to subscription ---
14 June 2022 14:50:47
--- Logging in to registry myreg.azurecr.io ---
Logging in to registry failed at 06/14/2022 14:50:57. Error: The term 'docker' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
14 June 2022 14:50:57
--- Confirming connected ---
{
  "adminUserEnabled": true,
  "anonymousPullEnabled": false,
  "creationDate": "2021-04-06T10:23:22.985285+00:00",
  --- OMMITTED --- 
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
  "zoneRedundancy": "Disabled"
}
[
  "myrepo1",
  --- OMMITTED --- 
  "myrepo2"
]
14 June 2022 14:51:11
--- Triggering build of myreg.azurecr.io/myimage:initial ---
2022/06/14 14:51:23 Downloading source code...
2022/06/14 14:51:29 Finished downloading source code
2022/06/14 14:51:30 Using acb_vol_77064302-024f-4c7c-8933-8f1fc9a4ce4f as the home volume
2022/06/14 14:51:31 Setting up Docker configuration...
2022/06/14 14:51:38 Successfully set up Docker configuration
2022/06/14 14:51:38 Logging in to registry: myreg.azurecr.io
2022/06/14 14:51:42 Successfully logged into myreg.azurecr.io
2022/06/14 14:51:42 Executing step ID: build. Timeout(sec): 28800, Working directory: '', Network: ''
2022/06/14 14:51:42 Scanning for dependencies...
2022/06/14 14:51:46 Successfully scanned dependencies
2022/06/14 14:51:46 Launching container with name: build

Sending build context to Docker daemon  804.4kB
Step 1/7 : FROM myreg.azurecr.io/myimage:empty
empty: Pulling from myimage
4612f6d0b889: Pulling fs layer
5ff1512f88ec: Pulling fs layer
--- OMMITTED ---
```

Comment: "the list of repositories is shown, no matter where it is called form." - how would you know? The `az acr repository list` command isn't logged?

Comment: Mathias, my initial script has lots of try/catches and logging for debugging. For the purposes of this question I pulled out all the actual calls being made. I didnt want to drop 100+ lines of code into the question.

Comment: I will edit to show full script..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the ACR BUILD command needed an absolute file path for the docker file and also <SOURCE_LOCATION>.

When called from the console, the current location was taken, but when the script was called from the scheduler it needed to be absolute.

So instead of:

```
az acr build -t $myimage$Date -r $myreg . --platform windows
```

It needed to be:

```
az acr build -t $myimage$Date -r $myreg -f c:/path-to-docker-file c:/path-to-source-folder/ --platform windows
```

The reason this was not evident to begin with, was because of the way I was capturing the logs. No errors or warnings were given when piping the output from ACR BUILD to **Out-File -FilePath $logfile**.

It was only when I switched to creating a transcript of the session (and removing the piped output) that an error was shown about not being able to see dockerfile.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "E:\transcript.txt" -NoClobber
```